# 1998 Jeep Grand Cherokee battery issues

Tags: battery, jump-start, battery-drain

Nearing 200,000 miles on this car, so it's beginning to have issues here and there. The most recent being that it dies when not being driven. This car was driven on a daily basis until I went to college, and then the issue began. My parents attempted to drive it, and found it dead. Jumping it took over 30 minutes to charge the battery up, and then it got a days worth of use before the car was left alone for a few months again. This repeated several times, and each time takes far longer to jump than it should. The batter is only 7 months old.

The only solution that we have come up with is that one of the interior lights (which is burnt out) was clicked on, and is drawing power without us realizing it. We've tried clicking it off, but have no idea if that's it, the light being burnt out and all. Is there any other solution that someone more mechanically knowledgeable can think of for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a relatively high (high for a sitting vehicle) drain on the batter. One which, if the vehicle was driven every day, would not affect it, but since it is not being driven that often is enough to kill the battery.

The easiest thing to do is to put a battery tender on it such as [this one from Beltran](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00068XCQU). There are many different brands out there which will do the job. Basically, it will keep you battery charged without the need for having it started every so often (though it's much better for the vehicle if you start it at least once a month).

Another thing you can do is just disconnect the battery when the vehicle is going to sit for a while. This will leave your battery without the drain on it.

If you want to try and figure out what the issue is, you'll need [an ammeter](http://www.delcity.net/store/5-Function-Digital-Snap!Around/p_797076.h_797077.t_1.r_IF1003?mkwid=aHEnkkZp&crid=38094426869&gclid=CjwKEAjwg7yqBRCu5NmlgMm6i08SJADDEudZqUEGGrpYRdLMsErh4gUS9TEOlhNlCrME0BqrPCNP8RoCiADw_wcB) which can detect the draw on the battery. Once you have this around your battery lead, you can start pulling fuses until you can find where the draw is coming from and fix it from there. The ammeter will show a drop in amperage draw when you find the right fuse.